# Difference Between Public and Private Selector Methods

Tags: selenium, scrapy

I'm just reading [this documentation here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) and was curious: **What is the difference between public and private methods in this context?**

> To find multiple elements (these methods will return a list):
>
> find_elements_by_name
>   find_elements_by_xpath
>   find_elements_by_link_text
>   find_elements_by_partial_link_text
>   find_elements_by_tag_name
>   find_elements_by_class_name
>   find_elements_by_css_selector
>   
>   Apart from the public methods given above, there are two private methods which might be useful with locators in page objects. These are the two private methods: find_element and find_elements.

I don't understand why some of those are public methods, whereas others are private methods, and it isn't explained anywhere.

From doing a test, I've noticed that there are differences in the `FirefoxWebElement` for public and private selectors.

## ***`find_element_by_xpath('//whatever')` returns***

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="234a0c66-870f-4fee-92b5-8d10541f2d2d", element="3275635e-614d-42da-95ac-306b02743bec")>
```

`session="234a0c66-870f-4fee-92b5-8d10541f2d2d"`
`element="3275635e-614d-42da-95ac-306b02743bec"`

## ***`find_element(By.XPATH, '//whatever')` returns***

```
<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="c792073f-08b3-4519-a563-0f1e272a17e7", element="b61a6d2d-2c35-4872-a8e0-2649c189829b")>
```

`session="c792073f-08b3-4519-a563-0f1e272a17e7"`
`element="b61a6d2d-2c35-4872-a8e0-2649c189829b"`

## **I'm not surprised that `session` is different, but why does it return a different value for `element`?!**

Comment: what is your question then ?

Comment: @cruisepandey in case my question wasn't clear, i've edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the definition of `find_element_by_xpath`

```
def find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath):
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
```

It uses the `find_element` method. Now why is `find_element` documented as private? Well few things

- The initial developer considered had personal preference to code it that way
- How would you find when you have source codes using `find_element_by_xpath` and some using `find_element(By.XPATH, "//div")`? Confusing, so best is to just keep it consistent
- Python is usually used in more english like manner, so `find_element_by_xpath` clear explains the intent
- Can one use `find_element` instead of `find_element_by_XXXX`? Why not, In my selenium helper library I use that only.

So those are my thoughts on the same, the original contributor to those line could probably tell his intentions were will making the method private

Comment: Ahhh, so that's why `find_element_by_xpath` is "public" and `find_element` is "private" i get it now

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get web element :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("some static id")
```

**and** :

```
element = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'some static id')
```

More or less they both are returning a **web element**.

So, `find_element()` which is a **private** method have some advantages such as :

If in case you want to locate the same element by **CSS_SELECTOR** or **XPATH** for new builds :

You would do something like :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("some css selector")
```

but in case of find_element() private method :

```
element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'some css selector')
```

As the official docs say : **private methods which might be useful with locators in page objects.**

**Page object** means for **maintainability** of your project and you will have your locators in either an INI file or in Page factory. So using Private method if you have to change something while doing regression or something , it would be easy to change the value at only one place.

Comment: hm... but there are public AND private XPath and CSS selectors? i do understand how to use each of them, but the part that i don't understand is "*`...with locators in page objects.`*" Can you expound on this bit?

Comment: i'm having troubles understanding you, sorry.

Comment: when you use a page factory, you will have to write your locator separately  and in future if something changes in UI , the locator would change , in that case you have to write locator and driver.find_element_by_id  may be changed to driver.find_element_by_xpath

Comment: But if you use driver.findElement() private method , you will not have to change the method i.e driver.fineElement() , just the locator inside it would do the job.

Comment: i'm still kind of confused. anyways, that documentation makes no mention of the fact that Selenium has another private method such as `driver,findElement`, but what you're saying is that if i were to use `driver.findElement` i could simply update the argument instead of the whole...?

Comment: For AUT , assume you have written driver.findElement(By.ID."id") , but after two builds , Dev team decided to generate random id , in that case your script will fail. So to make it to work , you have to just write drive.findElement(By.XPATH."xpath")  , but if you were using driver.fine_element_by_id("some id") , the whole method will have to change which will look something like : driver.fine_element_by_xpath("xpath") . Now I believe I have been able to clarify the things.

Comment: but why not just use `driver.find_element_by_xpath`?

Comment: you can use it , but here I am talking about only 1 web element , but it may be the case in which you have change for 50-100 methods. So using that would be helpful when you go with POM.

Comment: if youd have to change `driver.get_element/s_by_xpath` for 50-100 methods, why wouldnt you have to change `driver.find_element` for 50-100 methods? and what is POM? something object model?

Comment: Yes POM is page object model , this is the use case we have for driver.findElement() method over driver.find_element_by_id

Comment: im still not understanding, sorry :/