# Which is faster at parsing: Scrapy or Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

Disclaimer: I know there is obviously overhead when having to retrieve dynamically generated content with a web driver, but this question is about the ***parsing*** capability of each language. If you're going to down vote my question, it would be nice if you could leave an explanation!

***Simple question:*** **Is parsing with one framework more efficient than the other?**

```
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

browser.get(request.url)
```

***Transfering Dynamic Content to Scrapy for Parsing***

```
body = browser.page_source
response = HtmlResponse(browser.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
whatever = response.xpath('//whatever')
```

***Parsing with Selenium***

```
browser.get(request.url)
whatever = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//whatever')
```

Is one language more efficient than the other when the efficiency of parsing or is the difference insignificant once Selenium retrieves the dynamic content?

One reason I'm asking is that I find Scrapy much easier to use — much nicer syntax — so I'd certainly transfer over the `page_source` in order to parse with Scrapy if it won't or doesn't drastically effect the efficiency of my spider.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is a apple to orange comparison. `Scrapy` parsing is just in memory parsing at client side, while `selenium` is a browser controlling, your get actual rendered dom html and ofcourse it is way slower than `scrapy` in that case

The thing is anything that loads JS/CSS/Images will be much slower than the ones which just do parse the main html file. When you do

```
whatever = response.xpath('//whatever')
```

You have no overhead, it is just runs the xpath on the html document in memory. When you do

```
whatever = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//whatever')
```

It is JSON RPC command, so you have

```
          http                http/socket 
your code ----> browser agent ------------> browser
```

This has a much high overhead. Also browser is always slower then just downloading the html and parsing it

Comment: I understand that much. Well, I wasn't aware of Selenium having to execute all of its selector commands (i.e. `browser.find_elements_by_xpath`) with the browser as a middleman. So then if one were scraping quite a bit of data off of a single page, wouldn't it be faster to transfer over the `page_source` to Scrapy and then parse with Scrapy?!

Comment: Yes of course it would be, but the payoff would only be there when the amount of data one page is high and data to be scraped is huge (multiple pages)

Comment: I will be scraping tons of pages and there is quite a bit of data... How much scraping and how much data are you talking about, though?

Comment: Tables take a lot of time, so 10x10 table is a 100 http calls. So anytime it is beyond 10-15 fields, I will check the difference in timing and take a call

Comment: it's not a table element, even though the content is somewhat formatted like a table. basically just a bunch of cards with lots of little bits of info on each card in rows and columns! lemme know what the results of your test are!

Comment: I mean you can test how much delta in time it gives in both approach

Comment: eventually, the difference in efficiency isn't a huge priority at this very moment, but i will likely end up having to. do you know anything about [this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035651/difference-between-public-and-private-selector-methods)

Comment: i've just reread your answer since somebody down voted my question; so what you're saying is that, with selenium, once i retrieve a `page_source` response via `browser.get('https://google.com/'`, selenium doesn't cache that response and query the response itself?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173982/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-anthony).

Comment: can you please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090759/items-and-item-loaders). Btw, thanks for that link. I'm not sure how I missed it, but there was an "Architecture overview" page in the latest Scrapy documentation