# How do I extract text from a button using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape GoFundMe information but can't seem to extract the number of donors.

This is the html I am trying to navigate. I am attempting to retrieve 11.1K,

```
<ul class="list-unstyled m-meta-list m-meta-list--default">
  <li class="m-meta-list-item">
    <button class="text-stat disp-inline text-left a-button a-button--inline" data-element- 
    id="btn_donors" type="button" data-analytic-event-listener="true">
      <span class="text-stat-value text-underline">11.1K</span>&nbsp;
        <span class="m-social-stat-item-title text-stat-title">donors</span>
```

I've tried using

```
donors = soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'm-meta-list-item')
for donor in donors:
  print(donor.text)
```

The class/button seems to be hidden inside another class? How can I extract it?

I'm new to beautifulsoup but have used selenium quite a bit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please give us the link you are trying to scrape?

Comment: @insula https://www.gofundme.com/f/treatmentforsiyona?qid=7375740208a5ee878a70349c8b74c5a6

Answer (score 1):

These fundraiser pages all have similar html and that value is dynamically retrieved. I would suggest using selenium and a css class selector

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.gofundme.com/f/treatmentforsiyona?qid=7375740208a5ee878a70349c8b74c5a6')
num = d.find_element_by_css_selector('.text-stat-value').text
print(num)
d.quit()
```

---

Learn more about selenium:

```
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/27856
```

Comment: hi! css selector has not worked for me in this instance or with your line. I was trying to use beautiful soup but if you can edit your css selector to work, I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by didn't work?  Any error messages? I tested the above on several different pages including the one you supplied so I can only think that perhaps I need to add in a wait condition in case you are experiencing a timeout.

Comment: the web element exists, but no text is returned. No error.

Comment: And what happens if you put a short sleep in first in case you are accessing before the element updates?

Comment: still nothing prints :/

Comment: Most peculiar. Not sure what else to suggest other than to try the API suggested in the other answer.

Comment: @QHarr Thanks  a lot. Is there a difference between using this line `num = d.find_element_by_css_selector('.text-stat-value').text` and this line `num = d.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.text-stat-value').text` with the declaration of import `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`? What is the best aproach or both are the same?

Comment: @YasserKhalil https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51035651/difference-between-public-and-private-selector-methods

Answer (score 0):

get the id `gofundme.com/f/{THEID}` and call the API

```
/web-gateway/v1/feed/THEID/donations?sort=recent&limit=20&offset=20
```

process the Data

```
for people in apiResponse['references']['donations']
    print(people['name'])
```

use browser console to find host API.